# Регулярное выражение, непустой BB-код

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая регулярка `'~\[b]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/b]~s'` - что стоит изменить в ней, чтобы она не срабатывала, когда в тексте есть **только**  пробелы и переносы строк?

Comment: Учите язык регулярных выражений, а то по кругу вопросы задаете.

Comment: @Visman учу, и в процессе обучения задаю вопросы

Comment: По вашим вопросам не видно, что вы его учите. Так как вопросы все элементарные.

Answer (score 2):

> Вам нужна такая запись *(публикую два варианта решения)*:

```
<?php

$str = "[b]Текст! Текст![/b]
[b] 
Текст ,[/b]
[b]     Текст ?
Текст --  [/b]  [b]      [/b]

[b]     
 [/b]
[b][/b]";

$patt = '~\[b]\s*(\S)?(?(1)[\w\s!?:;,.-]+|\S+)\[/b]~u';
$all = preg_match_all($patt, $str , $a);

echo 'Совпадений: '. $all, '<pre>', print_r($a[0], true), '</pre>';


echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\[b]\s*(\S)?(?(1)[\w\s!?:;,.-]+|\S+)\[/b]~u',
    function ($a) {
        $a = preg_replace(['~\[/?b]~', '~\s+~'], ['', ' '], $a[0]);

        return '<b>' . $a . '</b>';
    },
    $str
);
```

> Результат:

```
Совпадений: 3
Array
(
    [0] => [b]Текст! Текст![/b]
    [1] => [b] 
Текст ,[/b]
    [2] => [b]     Текст ?
    Текст --  [/b]
)
```

**Текст! Текст! Текст , Текст ? Текст --** [b] [/b] [b] [/b] [b][/b]

Comment: чет не сработала как в примере выше https://regex101.com/r/7eFl0f/1

Comment: @Jean-Claude действительно ) Подправил ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, но не подскажите что делать, если регулярка не ловит русский текст?

Comment: @Владимир добавьте в шаблон модификатор `u`

Comment: @Эдуард добавил спасибо, а какой модификатор нужно добавить ещё, чтобы срабатывало на восклицательный знак и тд. т.е. не только на буквы?

Comment: @Владимир это уже не модификатором делается, а добавлением в шаблон символьного класса, соответствующего знакам препинания _(что бы вручную не прописывать их множество)_ Позже буду за ПК, подправлю шаблон.

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо Вам, жалко я не могу дать больше галочки, и голоса. Просто текст на сайте выводится произвольный, с любыми символами и тд. Вообщем пользовательский контент.

Comment: @Владимир обновил ответ _(дописал в шаблон возможные знаки препинания: !?:;,.-)_

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо. То есть регулярка не сможет словить к примеру такие символы - ♥ если их всех не перечислить в паттерне?

Comment: @Владимир вроде бы да.

Answer (score 2):

Общее решение подобных задач включает в себя исключающий блок предварительного просмотра вперёд:

```
'~\[b](?!\s*\[/b])\s*(.+?)\s*\[/b]~'
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/VyvrmJ/1). Однако для парсинга BB-кодов существуют специальные библиотеки (например, [jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/)).

**Подробности**

- `\[b]` - подстрока `[b]`
- `(?!\s*\[/b])` - после текущей позиции не должно быть 0+ пробельных символов, после которых следует подстрока `[/b]`
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `(.+?)` - 1 и более символов (как можно больше)
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `\[/b]` - подстрока `[/b]`

Comment: Спасибо, но что делать если текст имеет внутри буквы, и переносы строк (тогда регулярка не срабатывает)? Просто нужно, чтобы  она работала так же, если есть переносы или проблемы вместе с текстом, это ведь не считается пустота. Допустим "такой \n\r\n текст" не сработает, а должен..

Comment: @Владимир Вы что-то придумываете. `такой \n\r\n текст` содержит 2 слова, это *не* пробельные символы.